# IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets using query does not bring the correct value

Tags: google-docs

I'm trying to use query to filter the ImportRange function that I'm using to link 2 spreadsheets at google docs. The problem is that I'm trying to import just the cells where the column "CL." it's equal "CHW" and I'm seeing the message "Query completed with an empty output".

[image: From]

Somebody can help me in order to have this in my second spreadsheet? (without the line starting with "BEL" and without the first column "CL.").

[image: To]

I'm using this function: 
    =query(IMPORTRANGE("shared link","Tab1!B1:G30"),"select * where Col1='CHW'",0)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a little problem in my query and I fixed it. Basically I discovered that the query filter the result after fetching data, so, I just needed to change the query like this:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets...","General!A1:G22"),"select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col1='CHW'",0)
```